# Apt-get commands won't work

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg

On my ubuntu 15.04 server the apt-get command won't work. I think it has something to do with perl. Does anyone know how to fix it? I've already tried apt-get -f install, but that outputs the same error..

Thanks for helping me out

This is the error I receive:

```
root@xxx:~# apt-get install lynx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libncurses5 libncursesw5 libtinfo5 lynx-cur
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lynx lynx-cur
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libncurses5 libncursesw5 libtinfo5
3 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 568 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2426 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5731 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libtinfo5 libncursesw5 libncurses5 lynx-cur lynx
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: have you executed `sudo apt-get update` prior to this command?

Comment: I do, but then i receive the following error: W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org experimental InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Comment: You are using Debian archive on Ubuntu, which surely will bring you all sorts of problems. You should never do that, and should now remove all debian archives found in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/.

Comment: Please run `echo $PATH` in a root prompt and post the output.

Comment: *'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable* That doesn't look good.

Comment: Perhaps exiting from the root shell (whose PATH seems to be messed up) and using `sudo` (which should have its own secure_path) might make a difference?

Comment: Output from echo $PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games'.

Creating a new user didn't do the trick for me..